# ExecutionID changes in SSIS Package logging

Tags: sql-server-2008, logging, ssis

I was hoping to find an answer for this:

In sysssislog table, the executionID changes for the same package twice. For example, on the prevalidate phase, the executionID is `19EF7848-F626-4AF6-8B5F-0F419530597E`. But this executionID changes to `DA549ABD-27CC-4965-9DA0-FC701FB8F92C` when the package starts executing.

To find more information on this, I read the BOL entry about the sysssislog table and it states that (as a special note on ExecutionID):

> Running a single package might create log entries with different
>   values for the ExecutionID element. For example, when you run a
>   package in SQL Server Data Tools, the validation phase might create
>   log entries with an ExecutionID element that corresponds to SQL Server
>   Data Tools. However, the execution phase might create log entries with
>   an ExecutionID element that corresponds to dtshost.exe. For another
>   example, when you run a package that contains Execute Package tasks,
>   each of these tasks runs a child package. These child packages might
>   create log entries that have a different ExecutionID element than the
>   log entries that the parent package creates.

I am at a loss to understand this behavior. Shouldn't the executionID remain same throughout the execution of the package? I am considering using the packageGUID as my identifier so that I can get around this issue, but any help on this would be appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: Much as BOL states, if you're running a package from within BIDS (2005-2008R2)/SSDT (2012) the execution id for a package is going to fluctuate based on where in the stream of events processing is. If this is unacceptable, only run packages from the command-line (dtexec /file myPackage.dtsx) or through an Agent job. That will eliminate the opportunity for the validation phase to acquire a different execution id. I don't believe you have any recourse for child packages.

Comment: I dont have any child packages or such. All I have is a few execute sql tasks and DFT's (just 1 package). I am going to try out the command line method to see if that helps. I will report back what I find. Thanks.

Comment: It worked as you suggested. If you want to post this as an answer, I'd gladly accept it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much as BOL states, if you're running a package from within BIDS (2005-2008R2)/SSDT (2012) the execution id for a package is going to fluctuate based on where in the stream of events processing is. If this is unacceptable, only run packages from the command-line (`dtexec /file myPackage.dtsx`) or through an Agent job. That will eliminate the opportunity for the validation phase to acquire a different execution id. I don't believe you have any recourse for child packages.